# Avoid print calls in production code when using conditional statement

Tags: flutter, dart

If I use *classic* condition it works.

```
if (kDebugMode) {
    print(e.toString());
}
```

If I use conditional statement there is a warning:

> Avoid print calls in production code.

```
kDebugMode ? print(e.toString()) : {};
```

What's wrong with oneliner solution?

Comment: These two blocks of code are not the same if you look closely. in the classic one you are not declaring else block but in the second one you have to create one and as a result your code after : is a dead code.

Comment: The ternary operator is not the same as an `if`. You clearly want an `if`, so just use it? If you want a one-liner then just wrap your if-statement into a function and call that instead. It's better than plastering the same if-statement all over your code anyway.

Answer (score 0):

> What's wrong with oneliner solution?

Lots of things. You are obfuscating your code. You changed a super easy to understand `if` to a statement that is harder to parse for humans. You also added *additional code* that does nothing, just because the statement you picked for your logic *requires* it.

In short, yes, it works, but you picked the wrong language feature for what you want to do. You want to do X if Y is Z. That is best done using an `if`. The `?` operator is exactly that: an *operator* with a *result*. But you don't actually need a result so it looks convoluted and bloaty with dead code you had to add to make the compiler happy.

You need an `if`. So use an `if`. Not a different feature that if you torture it enough will give you the same result.

If you want that to be in one line, wrap your `if` in a method and call that instead. Might be a good idea anyway.

Answer (score -3):

```
  kDebugMode == true ? print(e.toString()) : {};
```

Comment: Why would that change anything?

Comment: kDebugMode by itself means nothing. It must be a condition. But when you use if you just assume that kDebugMode is true and continue. This is the difference between

Comment: `kDebugMode` is a `const bool`. There is no difference between saying `kDebugMode` and `kDebugMode == true`. Both evaluates to a bool of the value that `kDebugMode` has.

Comment: Anyway, did you check that the warning is no longer there when you do it your way?

Comment: conditional statement is working different not you mentioned

Comment: No, it actually isn't. But you don't need to believe me. Does your solution actually do what the OP asked? Does it make the warning disappear? You don't need to believe me, you can just try it.